# Finding image link in comment and add html tag to it

Tags: php

I have web application i need to add new function to it.

I allow user to post comment. Now what i want is if any user just post image url it should turn into proper with html tag. I am using php.

For example if user post just plan link of image, now i want it to add html tag to it itself.

```
Hi how are you? http://www.example.com/image/user/1.jpg have a good day!
```

And should look like this this:

```
Hi how are you? <img src="http://www.example.com/image/user/1.jpg"> have a good day!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this.

1. Parse posted content on URLs by regular expression.
2. Validate URLs on right images formats extensions (jpeg, jpg, png, ...) with some function.
3. If in URL is image file location - replace it with `<img>` tag.

Comment: need to check extensions in whole content and then replace with image tag seems good idea also bit hard :)